# How does Ruby generate random numbers using

Tags: ruby, random

So when using, for example, rand(10), how does ruby generate the random number? I have very little knowlege about random number generation techniques, so I would like to get to know them better.

Comment: Your question is really, "How are pseudo random numbers generated? Only someone well aware of the various algorithms used would want to know how it's done in Ruby; that is, which algorithm does Ruby use. Your question therefore has nothing to do with Ruby and therefore should be closed (and I have voted to do so). Moreover, your question is not really appropriate for any Stack Exchange user group. Your first step is obviously to do some basic research. Try googling "pseudo random number generators".

Answer (score 2):

Ruby is [open-source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby). I'll demonstrate how to locate the PRNG (pseudo random number generator) code, as there's no way to generate truly random numbers using a deterministic CPU.

Looking at the repository, we see a [suspiciously-named file, random.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ruby/ruby/trunk/random.c). Looking inside, it's in C, but that's ok, it has comments. The first function is genrand_real, calling genrand_int32, which takes a struct MT. This function is defined in [mt19937.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/18365f9e83ef8f8402426024de4777f1f831ba37/missing/mt19937.c) and looking at that file, it uses bitwise operations to get the next state of the random number generator and applies more bitwise operators to generate the number desired.

Comment: Note that this is only one of many Ruby implementations. There is no guarantee that Rubinius, JRuby, IronRuby, Opal, MRuby, MagLev, … will have the same implementation. In fact, JRuby's, IronRuby's, MagLev's, and Opal's implementation will very likely not even be in the same language. Also, there *were* closed-source implementations of Ruby, e.g. MacRuby, RubyMotion, BlueRuby.

Comment: Most of which are based on cRuby, in the end.